# How to change the registered mailbox

Tags: support

I register the SE account by `***@gmail.com`.But now I want to change my mailbox to `***@163.com`.This action is admited in this site?

Comment: Try going [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/me).

Comment: @J.M. Wow.this help me a lot.Thank very much. :)

Comment: If you were able to change your address, write an answer to your own question explaining how you did it.

Comment: @J.M. Ok.I'll call the person that actually operate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm the one who actually operate that. I'll have to say it's quite hard to do this. Even **THRILLING** when I deleted my SE profile and try to reperform my act.

Here is the tutorial:

1. Go to this website and check your existing login ways.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/me

And if you have multiple login method, this is whay you'll see:

[image: img1]

2. You can delete login method simply by clicking the small **remove** button. There'll be a small window to confirm this action, click **Yes** will be alright:

[image: img2]

Then you'll see that your account has been deleted......

[image: img2.1]

3. You can add login method by clicking the **add more login** button

You will be directed to this page:

[image: img3]

If you would love to add a normal account, simply click on them and follow the procedure. For example, if you would love to use google account, Google will show you a series of validation process, then SE will also check wheter you would like to use this account. It would be quite simple.

However, it could be annoying if you want to add an account with SE. So follow me:

First get to the page as well and input **stackexchange.com** in the input field. Then click **Add Credential** button:

[image: img3]

Then you shall see a webpage showing you the **StackExchange OPEN ID**. If you already logged in with one, you can directly use it. Otherwise you can Click the **login** button and input the e-mail address you have as well as the password. If you don't, try register one.

Then you can see that you successfully add a new login method for your SE account!

[image: img1]

And for me, I can finally get my account back to normal......

---

It's truely aweful to post all kinds of questions and solutions with my tiny cellphone! My fingers hurt…… I'll need upvotes to compensate my pain! :/

Comment: My fault.This my first time to hear somebody can use cell phone to post such long answer.. :)

Comment: Just curious, how do you use Mathematica if you only have cellphone to post your question/answers?

Comment: @happyfish Sometimes I will just run my code in my head, sometimes I will run it on my computer and send them to my phone. I don't have VPN on my computer, so It's not possible for me to log in my account on my computer. :)

Comment: @Wjx From my experience, once you successfully login your SE account in mainland China, no more VPN is required for subsequent posting/searching. Perhaps you can use some temporary free VPN once to login on your computer.

Comment: @happyfish but when using VPN your location will not be identified as in mainland china~

Comment: @Wjx when I said mainland China, I mean I tested that method in mainland China

Comment: @Wjx I am Chinese, and that's the method I used to use SE when I am in mainland China. Hope that helps.

Comment: @happyfish wow, really? So I can get a temprory VPN and login forever? I will try it,  thanks!